# Splitting App Administration Panel In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am currently using the Django admin panel on an app that has 10 different models. When I log in, I click on the app and I see 10 different urls which lead to dashboards in which I can add/edit/delete data.

The customer wants these models to be split into two different panels, 5 models each. I could move the 5 models to a separate app, but I am wondering if I can configured the admin panel to do this via Django.

Comment: What Django Version? If you're in 1.7 you can probably do this with the new Applications AppConfig https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications

Comment: Consider upgrading or go with your original idea of splitting up your app.